# TFAGENTS: Valid/Invalid actions for REINFORCE agents

Tags: tensorflow, reinforcement-learning

When creating a **DQN** agents with TFAGENTS it's possible to specify
a function to mask valid/invalid actions.

This is done by specifying the [observation_and_action_constraint_splitter](https://www.tensorflow.org/agents/api_docs/python/tf_agents/agents/DqnAgent) function.

Apparently it's not possible to do the same for a **[REINFORCE](https://www.tensorflow.org/agents/api_docs/python/tf_agents/agents/ReinforceAgent)** agent.

How can I mask valid/invalid actions when using **REINFORCE** agents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

It seems there is an out of the box to do this by implementing a [`MaskSplitterNetwork`](https://www.tensorflow.org/agents/api_docs/python/tf_agents/networks/mask_splitter_network/MaskSplitterNetwork):

Assuming the filter function is in the form of:

```
def filter_fun(observation):
    return observation['observation'], observation['legal_moves']
```

Create the actor network (and if required, the value network) and wrap it unsing the MaskSplitterNetwork constructor:

```
masked_actor_network = mask_splitter_network.MaskSplitterNetwork(
    splitter_fn=filter_fun,
    wrapped_network=actor_distribution_network.ActorDistributionNetwork(
        train_env.observation_spec()['observation'],
        train_env.action_spec(),
        fc_layer_params=fc_layer_params
    ),
    passthrough_mask=True
)
```

And feed the masked actor network into the reinforce agent

```
agent = reinforce_agent.ReinforceAgent(
    train_env.time_step_spec(),
    train_env.action_spec(),
    actor_network=masked_actor_network,
    optimizer=optimizer,
    normalize_returns=True,
    train_step_counter=train_step_counter,
)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'd like to see this included in TFAgents library out of the box!

Comment: I found a way to do it out of the box, using some utility from tf_agents.networks